# Null check groovy way result of database query

Tags: grails, groovy

This might seem simple but it's my first time dealing with groovy and database interactions

I have to get something from the database and check if it's *NOT NULL*, I'll throw an Exception

`PaymentDetails details = PaymentDetails.findById(id)`

What is the groovy way to check if the `details` is *NOT NULL*?

Is condition seems wrong :(

```
if (!details) {
    println("ERROR!!!!")
    throw new InvalidException()
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (details) {
    println("ERROR!!!!")
    throw new InvalidException()
}
```

Refer to docs on [The Groovy Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) to understand how Groovy decides on boolean expressions.

Comment: Note that `if(details)` there isn't just checking `null`.  That expression will evaluate to `false` if `details` is `null`, the number zero (0), an empty `String`, an empty `Collection` or an empty `Map` (others too, depending on what type of object `details` is).